# generate new controller not working in phoenix-elixir?

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

Good day, I have been trying hard to generate a new controller in phoenix with elixir, but I'm getting this error:

```
The task "phoenix.gen.controller" could not be found
```

but I can manually create the file which I do not know the breakdown of doing it.

I'm using:

```
Elixir 1.2.6
Erlang OTP 18
```

Will appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, did you add Phoenix into your `mix.exs`? If so, there's no `phoenix.gen.controller` task, but for generating controllers you have two options- using `html` for generating controller with HTML view or `json` for preparing API with JSON.

Go check [this](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Json.html#content) out.

I mentioned about two of these:

```
mix phoenix.gen.html    # Generates controller, model and views for an HTML based resource
mix phoenix.gen.json    # Generates a controller and model for a JSON based resource
```

Comment: will read it now. but I'm following this tutorial http://phoenix.thefirehoseproject.com/2.html and I'm where I will have to add thequote_controller. So i thought that you do it doing the above command @PatNowak

Comment: can you do this mix phoenix.gen.html inside the web/ folder generated at the start of a new project?

Comment: Yes, it suppose to generate the files there, because the content of `web` folder is the part of application you would like to develop. You don't have go there. You can run this command in the root folder of application.